# create a list with content of multiple zip files in linux

Tags: linux, zip

I am trying to create a script for linux that will make a list with all files inside all zip files from a directory.

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in `find /home -iname "*.zip*" -type f`
do
unzip -l $(echo ${file}) >> /home/list.txt
done
```

It works, but only when there are no white spaces in filename.
What can I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **find** command to execute a command for each file it finds. Perhaps try something like:

```
find /home -iname "*.zip*" -type f -exec unzip -l {} \; > /home/list.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to print to list.txt only files that have a certain extension ? For example only .txt files to be in list.txt.

Comment: You could try something like:

`find /home -iname "*.zip*" -type f -exec unzip -l {} \; | grep -e \.txt > /home/list.txt`